# Prevent a directory listed in gallery app

Tags: android

I am working on a chat application where I am sending/receiving Images/ Media. I am writing those files in a directory both sent and received.
Now the problem is if I send an image from gallery in chat I am copying it into `Sdcardpath + AppName/Images/Sent/`. 
I this case the images in sent folder are duplicate.
And gallery app is Showing Sent folder with images. I need a way so that gallery cannot read the SentFolder. Below is my code for creating directory.

```
 public static File getImageSentDirectory() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + DOCUMENT_FILE_SENT_PATH);
        if (!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();
        return dir;
    } else {
        File dir = new File(getAppContext().getFilesDir() + DOCUMENT_FILE_SENT_PATH);
        if (!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();
        return dir;
    }
}
```

I also tried .

```
dir.setWritable(true,true);
dir.setReadable(true,true);
```

But on restart device gallery app is showing the sent folder with images .

Comment: If you don't want Gallery app to list your folder make an empty ".nomedia" file in your directory programmatically.

Comment: A file inside directory ? or i have to name  Sent folder as .nomedia? As i have seen WhatsApp's Directory structure and there is nothing like .nomedia .

Comment: you do not need to create a new directory. `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory ()` or `getAppContext (). GetFilesDir ()` are directorys.See this https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html and https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need a way so that galery can not read the SentFolder.

Do not put `SentFolder` on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html). Put it on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

The `.nomedia` suggestion may help, but it is a convention, not a rule. Any app that has read access to external storage can get to any files you put on external storage. If you do not want that, do not put the files on external storage.

Comment: Yes but he said "Prevent a directory listed in gallery app". And additionally, mentioned SDcardpath. If he hadn't mentioned SD Card then your method is correct.

Comment: @abybaddi009: "Yes but he said "Prevent a directory listed in gallery app"." -- there are ~2 billion Android devices, spread across ~10,000 device models. There are dozens, if not hundreds, of pre-installed "gallery" apps, and there are many more that can be installed from the Play Store or elsewhere. *None* of them have to honor `.nomedia`. "And additionally, mentioned SDcardpath" -- the code has nothing to do with "SDcardpath".

Comment: OK master. I'm sorry. I take it back.

Comment: Thanks for answers . This make sense.

Comment: @CommonsWare Internal storage is bit limited in android, is it good practice to use internal to save Media? At some point if internal is full how can i will handle it with application?

Comment: @Diazdiaz: "Internal storage is bit limited in android" -- internal storage and external storage are on the same partition on the vast majority of Android 3.0+ devices. "is it good practice to use internal to save Media?" -- IMHO, the best thing to do is ask the user whether to use on-board flash (internal storage/external storage) or removable storage (if the user has any). After all, it is the user's device. "At some point if internal is full how can i will handle it with application?" -- display a dialog saying that the device is out of disk space, for starters.

Answer (score 3):

Add a .nomedia file in your "Sent" directory.
This will make the "Gallery" app skip your folder and thus it won't be listed.

The .nomedia file is like this inside WhatsApp media directory. It is a zero byte file.

[image: nomedia file]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i think i will conclude this one and Commonsware's suggestion . And yeah whatsApp do have .nomedia file . Last time i checked it was hidden . Thx again